# How to place suggestedactions button as I want

Tags: c#, botframework

Hello I'm a beginner developer.

I would like to show the suggestedactions buttons in two columns on multiple lines. (ex 2 column 3 row) I only know how to show it in one row. Please teach me if there is a way.

Thank You

Below is an example of the code.

```
welcomeActivity.SuggestedActions = new SuggestedActions()
{
    Actions = new List<CardAction>()
    {
        new CardAction(){ Title = Common.SomeResource1, Type=ActionTypes.ImBack, Value= Common.SomeResource1},
        new CardAction(){ Title = Common.SomeResource2, Type=ActionTypes.ImBack, Value= Common.SomeResource2},
        new CardAction(){ Title = Common.SomeResource3, Type=ActionTypes.ImBack, Value= Common.SomeResource3},
        new CardAction(){ Title = Common.SomeResource4, Type=ActionTypes.ImBack, Value= Common.SomeResource4},
        new CardAction(){ Title = Common.SomeResource5, Type=ActionTypes.ImBack, Value= Common.SomeResource5},
        new CardAction(){ Title = Common.SomeResource6, Type=ActionTypes.ImBack, Value= Common.SomeResource6},
    }
};
```

Comment: Did you use the azure bot SDK v3 ?

Comment: What channel are you targeting? The only channels that this is probably possible in is the WebChat or DirectLine using the [BotFramework-WebChat](https://github.com/microsoft/BotFramework-WebChat) repo which allows you to customise styles, this requires using Javascript though. The part you are probably interested in is the [carousel](https://github.com/microsoft/BotFramework-WebChat/blob/24672f793c27e9e19b68736ed223d544ac17f9ff/packages/component/src/Styles/StyleSet/SuggestedActionsStyleSet.js#L50).

Comment: azure bot version is SDK v4.

Comment: I plan to use multiple channels and include webchat. Do I need to use JavaScript in addition to carousels?

Comment: This has everything to do with the channel client and has nothing to do with bot code. What other channels are you using? And will you be satisfied with only accomplishing this in Web Chat or will you only accept an answer that works in all channels?

Comment: I will do the coding separately for each channel.
The channels I will use will be Skype and Facebook, Web Chat,  line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my experience Suggested Actions does not work very well in the Webchat channel, as I could not move the suggestions to appear in my chat frame (the chat box). To be clear, I am using Bot Framework v4.

The alternative that I used was a HeroCard which works well in multiple channels. I have implemented the suggestions like this:

```
var card = new HeroCard()
{
    Text = "Would you like me to help you?",
    Buttons = new List<CardAction>()
    {
       new CardAction(){ Title = "Yes", Type = ActionTypes.ImBack, Value = "Yes" },
       new CardAction(){ Title = "No", Type = ActionTypes.ImBack, Value = "No" },
    }
}; 

//To display the HeroCard, you need to send it as PromptOptions like this.
return await stepContext.PromptAsync("dialogName",
            new PromptOptions
            {
                Choices = ChoiceFactory.ToChoices(new List<string> { "Yes", "No" }),
                Prompt = (Activity)MessageFactory.Attachment(card.ToAttachment()),                             
            }, cancellationToken);
```

Comment: Thanks Evander_F, If so, is it possible to lay out the 3-row, 2-column format that I initially wanted with a hero card? If possible, please show a code example.

Comment: As far as I know you cannot add a 3-row, 2-column format for the HeroCard but you can create a Carousel of HeroCards (with three buttons each) and present it to the user. I have tested this on Web Chat and Facebook.